# Joint distribution of two random variables from SDEs

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I need to calcute the probability $P( X > k, Y < k)$
where both $X$ and $Y$ are random normal variables.

What I would like to know is, if $W$ is brownian motion, and $X = \int_0^1 \sigma dW$ and $Y = \int_0^2 \sigma dW$, then it is known that they are normally distributed variables .... but probably not independent.

How would one then go about calculating $P(X > k, Y < k)$?